# как связать две и более коллекции в firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firestore

например, первая коллекция содержит имя композитора, а вторая коллекция работы(произведения),
[image: список композиторов]
если пользователь загрузил первым список композиторов и выбирая композитора должен появиться список его произведения,

[image: список произведении]
а если пользователь загрузил первым произведение и при выборе автора должен ссылаться на композитора из первой коллекции(то есть должна же быть какая то связь между двумя коллекциями), если есть на это какие то уроки буду признателен, я только вникаю в бэк firebase так что не судите меня строго. Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 3):

Сделайте коллекцию `composers` в ней документы с именами композиторов. В каждом документе сделайте вложенные коллекции bio, works... В клиентской части вы будете загружать коллекцию composers, и при нажатии подгружать нужные вложенные коллекции. Как-то так

Comment: а если я хочу вывести отдельно топ-10 - 25-100 произведении сразными композиторами?

Comment: Тогда структура будет другой, работы будут отдельной коллекцией, в каждом документе укажите composer: "Name", rating: "3". В клиентской части получите всю коллекцию целиком, а дальше фильтруйте ответ от сервера, используя методы массивов. Дальше если надо будет перейти к биографии автора вы запросите нужный документ из коллекции "composers".

Comment: а потом можно будет каскадным образом менять имя композитора, поменял в одном месте - везде поменялся?